# Лексический вопрос

Tags: фразеология

Как правильно написать: "Великая победа", или "великая Победа", или "Великая Победа" если речь идёт о Великой Отечественной войне?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В последнее время устоялись вот такие формы поздравления :

Поздравляем с Днем Великой Победы!

С праздником Великой Победы!

Заглавные буквы приветственных поздравлений подчеркивают особую значимость праздника.
Что касается обычного текста,  то возможны варианты в зависимости от степени торжественности (пафоса). "Народ в 45-м одержал великую победу над фашизмом, но впереди были еще тяжелые годы восстановления страны" /// "Многонациональный советский народ долгих четыре года сражался как один за великую Победу, он выстоял и по праву победил в этой жестокой битве!"

Эмоциональный накал во втором случае явно выше, и заглавная буква там к месту.

Comment: Я совершенно согласен с Вами. Спасибо за компанию. Сила проявления эмоциональности подчёркивается наличием или отсутствием заглавных букв в тексте. Разумеется, если великая победа была только впереди, она ещё не имела того влияния на психику людей: воинов,тружеников тыла и наследников Победы, которое стало ощущаться потом, по мере удаления самого события вглубь Истории. Для самих воинов это был труд, тяжкий, смертельно опасный, где ещё ничего не было ясно для самого индивидуума, а для выживших Победителей и, тем более, для нас, их наследников, - это уже только воспоминания и эмоции.